# Using perl to change multi-line expression

Tags: perl

I have a file which contains

```
...

CNN
111
XXX

ABC
111
XXX

ABC
111
BBC

...
```

and I need to change the 111 to 999 but only as part of ABC\n111\nXXX

```
...

CNN
111
XXX

ABC
999
XXX

ABC
111
BBC

...
```

I have tried this, but it changes "111" everywhere.

```
perl -i -pe '/ABC\n111\nXXX/ if s/111/999/g' FILE
```

Note: We need to compare multiple lines as "111" might be in many other places. The file size is 227kb.

Comment: All-caps text and nondescript titles are not OK.

Comment: How big is the file roughly? There are essentially two approaches, the easy one where you read the entire file into memory and the harder one where you process it a few lines at a time.

Comment: @Farhana Please login back on again before trying to edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -0777 -i -p -e 's/ABC\n111\nXXX/ABC\n999\nXXX/g;' file
```

the -0777 puts perl into `slurp` mode so it reads the whole file. Then the substitute command makes the needed change.